# Create a React component to utilize other React Components

Tags: reactjs, react-native

from an array inside an object and renders it to the browser. The App uses a number of small components Header, Contents and Total to function.

Next part of exercise is to create a single component 'Course' to do the same job as all the smaller components(Header,Contents,Total)

Here is original app that gives this output:

Half Stack application development

Fundamentals of React10

Number of exercises is 31

```
import React from 'react'
```

```
const Header = (props) => {

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.course}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

const Content = (props) => {
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{props.part1}</p>
    </div>
  )
  }

const Part = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
     <p>{props.part1} {props.exercises1}</p> 
    </div>
  )
}

const Total = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Number of exercises is {props.total}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  const course = {
    name: 'Half Stack application development',
    parts: [
      {
        name: 'Fundamentals of React',
        exercises: 10
      },
      {
        name: 'Using props to pass data',
        exercises: 7
      },
      {
        name: 'State of a component',
        exercises: 14
      }
    ]
  }

  return (
    <div>
    <Header course={course.name} />
    <Content part1 = {course.parts[0].name + course.parts[0].exercises} />
    <Total total = {course.parts[0].exercises + course.parts[1].exercises  + course.parts[2].exercises} />
        </div>

  )
}

export default App
```

And here is the new component I created which is giving me a blank output, no errors reported

```
const Course = (props) => {
return (
 <div>
   <Header></Header>
   <Content></Content>
   <Total></Total>
 </div>
)
}

With updated App

onst App = () => {
const course = {
 name: 'Half Stack application development',
 parts: [
   {
     name: 'Fundamentals of React',
     exercises: 10
   },
   {
     name: 'Using props to pass data',
     exercises: 7
   },
   {
     name: 'State of a component',
     exercises: 14
   }
 ]
}

return <Course course={course} />
}

export default App
```

Comment: Do you have an actual question or issue somewhere in your post? The last example `Course` is rendering empty children components.

Comment: Ya sorry, I thought how I created the Course component would use the other components, so I am asking how should I structure the Course component to use the other components(Header, Contect) to get the same output as original App.

Comment: How do you want `name` and `exercise` values to map to the `course`, `part1`, `exercise1`, and `total` props used by the various components? You're question needs to provide a bit more context and describe desired behavior and any issues in trying to do so.

Comment: Not sure are you saying my question doesn't make any sense?

Comment: Oh, I see.... the code you factored out into the `Course` component needs to render the same thing then.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not been clear